# given $xf''(x) + f'(x)+f(x)\leq 0\,\forall x > 0.$ Find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to\mathbb{R}^+$ be a twice-differentiable function so that $xf''(x) + f'(x)+f(x)\leq 0\,\forall x > 0.$  Find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$.

It may be useful to consider a function $g(x)$ defined in terms of $f,f',$ and/or $f''$. We have $(\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)})' = \dfrac{f''(x)f(x)-f'(x)^2}{f(x)^2}, (x\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)})' = \dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} +x\dfrac{f''(x)f(x)-f'(x)^2}{f(x)^2} = \dfrac{f'(x)f(x) + xf''(x)f(x)-f'(x)^2 x}{f(x)^2}.$ Adding 1 to the latter derivative gives $\dfrac{f(x)(xf''(x)+f'(x)+f(x)) - f'(x)^2 x}{f(x)^2}.$  The MVT or Taylor's theorem might be useful too. I was also thinking of finding specific functions that actually satisfy the inequality to have a better idea of what approach to use. Note that no linear polynomial or constant $f(x)$ satisfies the inequality in the question. If $f=ax^2 + bx+c$ then $xf''(x) + f'(x) + f(x) = x(2a) + 2ax+b + ax^2 + bx+c$ and so by the inequality we must have $a < 0.$ But this is impossible since $f(x)>0\,\forall x.$ Hence f cannot be a quadratic either.

Comment: The codomain of $f$ being $\mathbf{R}^+$ is important here. If you allow negative values of $f$, then $f(x) = c$ with $c \leq 0$ satisfied the condition and can achieve any negative limit.

Comment: @DamianPavlyshyn you're right. I initially forgot about that when I tried to come up with an example with a quadratic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $f$ that satisfies your condition, we have that it must not have any local minima; Indeed if $f$ had a local minima at $x = a$ we have that $f(a) >0, f'(a) = 0$ and $f''(a) \geq 0$ which would make $f(a) +f'(a)+af''(a) > 0$. This means that $f$ is eventually strictly decreasing or strictly increasing.

Therefore $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists (could be infinite). $\textbf{We claim that this limit is}$ $0$.

For proof by contradiction, if $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)$ is non-zero then there exists $c > 0$ and $M \in \mathbb{R}$ so that  $f(x) \geq c$ for $x \geq M$. In particular

$$xf''(x)+f'(x) +c \leq 0 \text{ for }x \geq M$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{d}{dx}(xf'(x)) \leq -c \text{ for }x \geq M$$

Thus for sufficiently large $x$, say $x \geq N \geq M$ we have that $xf'(x) \leq -\frac{c}{2}x$ or $f'(x) \leq \frac{-c}{2}$. Thus $f$ diverges to $-\infty$ which is impossible.

Thus the limit is $0$.

Comment: I think it's possible that f is eventually decreasing or increasing. f may eventually be constant, but just because it doesn't have any local minima doesn't necessarily mean it has to eventually be strictly decreasing or strictly increasing.

Comment: Is there a version of this argument that works if we only restrict $f$ to $[0, \infty)$? In this case, the condition still allows for "flat" local minima where $f(a) = f''(a) = 0$, but my guess is that the result should still hold.